# Rails 3 - Delayed_job 4.x

Tags: ruby-on-rails, delayed-job

I am using delayed_job to generate reports in my rails application along with paperclip to store it in s3. With dj 3.0.5 everything was working fine, as i have upgraded to dj 4.0.0 sometimes the file is not even generated and the delayed job process is finished without any error.

Is there anything major that have been changed in dj 4.0.0, as in changelog i cannot find any major changes w.r.t. dj 3.0.5.

Answer (score 0):

Major version number changes typically signify . From **[semver.org](http://semver.org/)**

> Major version X (X.y.z | X > 0) MUST be incremented if any backwards incompatible changes are introduced to the public API.

Since `delayed_job` is on Github, it's particularly easy to browse all the changes that have been made between the releases you mention via the browser.

- https://github.com/collectiveidea/delayed_job/compare/v3.0.5...v4.0.0

Their `README` doesn't explicitly say they follow semver, and I don't follow their changelog well enough to offer potential suggestions as to what could be causing your problem. The major version change does suggest something BC-breaking may have been done.

I'd suggest checking your logs and trying to debug the issue further on your own if you're seeking more *specific* advice.

Answer (score 0):

## Solution

You're missing the upgrade migration. After updating the gem run the following

```
rails generate delayed_job:upgrade
rake db:migrate
```

## Details

This is in the [Github README](https://github.com/collectiveidea/delayed_job/#upgrading-from-2x-to-300-on-active-record) however it says it's only for going from v2.x to v3.0.0.

I ran into the same problem myself today. We just went from v3.0.3 to v4.1.1. I didn't believe I had to do this based on the README but after I looked at the changes it would make and the errors I had, I determined that there must be some set of installs or upgrades within v3.x or from v3 to v4 that require this migration as well.